# How to set conditional config options in flatpickr

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I am successfully using [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) as my favorite date picker, but now I have to make the "defaultDate" input conditional.

```
if(defDateExists){
    defaultDate: ucheckout,
}
```

That breaks my function. I have no idea how to use options conditionally. Please help. Thanks!

```
function _flattie() {
    const fpx = flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
        minDate: new Date().fp_incr(1), // 1 days from now
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
        disableMobile: "true",
        if(defDateExists){
            defaultDate: checkout,
        }
        monthSelectorType: "static",
        inline: true,
        onChange: function() {
            selectedDate = new Date(tempDate).toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            stringDate = new Date(tempDate).toString("MMM dS yyyy"); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [ternary conditionals](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
function _flattie() {
const fpx = flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
    minDate: new Date().fp_incr(1), // 1 days from now
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    disableMobile: "true",
    defaultDate: defDateExists ? checkout : null,
    monthSelectorType: "static",
    inline: true,
    onChange: function() {
        selectedDate = new Date(tempDate).toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        stringDate = new Date(tempDate).toString("MMM dS yyyy"); 
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for supporting me with this! Tried that. And that's the console response: `Uncaught ReferenceError: defDateExists is not defined`

Comment: mmm, i was thinking that variable exists in your code as a control variable

Comment: you can do simpler in this case: "defaultDate:  checkout || null"
Its a ternary OR operator if checkout exists set the value if not set null

Comment: holy...! yes it does. I had a typo in the variable. works! thanks! case closed! thanks so much!